# heroku push code issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, module, fs

I just tried to push my code to heroku, but I got this error

=============================

```
27 http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs
28 silly registry.get cb [ 404,
28 silly registry.get { server: 'CouchDB/1.3.1 (Erlang OTP/R15B03)',
28 silly registry.get date: 'Mon, 16 Dec 2013 04:40:31 GMT',
28 silly registry.get 'content-type': 'application/json',
28 silly registry.get 'content-length': '52',
28 silly registry.get 'cache-control': 'must-revalidate' } ]
29 silly lockFile a107b96b-fs fs@
30 silly lockFile a107b96b-fs fs@
31 error 404 'fs' is not in the npm registry.
31 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it
31 error 404
31 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
31 error 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
32 error System Darwin 13.0.0
33 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "fs"
34 error cwd /Users/Luke/Documents/dtmstudio/app/nodetest1
35 error node -v v0.10.22
36 error npm -v 1.3.14
37 error code E404
38 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
! Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

===============================

I just removed all the fs reference in my code, but i still go this error, why?
I know that fs is the module in nodejs 0.10.23 by default, there is no npm installation required.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It probably appears in your `package.json`. Remove it from there.